# PHP $count should never be higher then $total

Tags: php

I have following code and I want to refactor it:

```
if ($count > $total) {
    $count = $total;
}
```

So I'ill just check if count is higher then total and if this is true I set `$count` to `$total`.

But I found a new method, but im not sure how I can make it fit into my case, or if it fits in general:

```
$count = max($count, $total);
```

The problem here is that this will always give me the highest number. But I only want the highest number if `$count` is higher then `$total`.
If `$total` is higher then `$count` then I do not want to change count at all.

Is there any solution in how I can do this without an if statement? Like a function that fits perfectly for my case?

What do I want to archive?

I want to make sure that `$count` is never higher then `$total`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want `min`, not `max`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol is right. Think about it 2 more minutes. You say you want the highest if $count is higher than $total. This is false! If count is higher, you want $total. So you want the lowest :)

Comment: Ok yes. It looks like I was a bit confused about this. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` will always return you maximum value from array.
you can try shorter code for this:

```
$count = ($count > $total) ? $total : $count;
```

Or you can use min

```
$count=min($count,$total);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `min()` instead of `max()`

```
$count=min($count,$total);
```